# Export page to pdf in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, export

I'm looking for a good option to have an export to pdf functionality on each of my app's pages using angular. Does anyone have any recommendations on angular modules that can achieve this as I haven't been able to find any angular based ones.

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [angular-save-html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-save-html-to-pdf)

```
   //Here goes your script in html file
   <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
   <script src="../dist/saveHtmlToPdf.min.js"></script>

    //Add this module to your angular app :
    var app = angular.module('app' , ['htmlToPdfSave']) ;

     //This is your html file
    <button pdf-save-button="idOneGraph" pdf-name="hello.pdf" class="btn">Hello World</button>

     <!-- below block will be saved as pdf -->

     <div pdf-save-content="idOneGraph" >
              Hello World
         </div>
```